# Buscar en JSON array mysql

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb

dispongo de una tabla en mi base de datos llamada systems, con un registro llamado OS que contiene distintos campos y uno de estos es un LONGTEXT llamado settingsOS, necesito buscar un valor en un array de objetos JSON y que me devuelva el objeto entero.

Me gustaría que se hiciera la búsqueda por llave "osID" que sea equivalente a 11 mediante consulta SQL... No se por donde empezar si quiera si se puede,este es el array

```
[{"osId":3,"settings":{"isEnabled":true,"isLocked":true,"desc":"Windows 10"}},
{"osId":11,"settings":{"isEnabled":false,"isLocked":true,"desc":"Windows 7"}}]
```

Esperando así que buscando por osId de 11 me devuelva: `{"osId":11,"settings":{"isEnabled":false,"isLocked":true,"desc":"Windows 7"}}`

Comment: Has probado un "WHERE settingsOS LIKE '%\"osID\":11%'" ? Es decir, pon un filtro where correspondiente

Comment: No, no me hace la búsqueda :(

Comment: puedes probar tambien JSON_EXTRACTS (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_contains/). Echa un vistazo en este otro SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52083608/mysql-mariadb-json-extract-and-json-contains, parece que la respuesta puede ayudarte

Comment: ¿Está usando MySQL o MariaDB? ¿Qué versión exactamente?

Comment: @wchiquito 10.4.22-MariaDB

Comment: Aquí una opción (ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=192217426fc3e59ceb347512317420ab)) que puede darle ideas.